# How to fill multiple TextViews randomly from a list of numbers?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm making some kind of game and want to fill 9 TextViews with numbers (1-9) like the image below:

[image]

I want the TextViews to get filled randomly every time the activity is created. How can I make it work?

Comment: Simple way add one to nine number in array list then shuffle your list, and display inside recycler view with the grid layout manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a seperate method to create an array and use Java's shuffle method to change the order of the list. Afterwards, you can assign each one by index to your text views.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Example {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      list.add(1);
      list.add(2);
      list.add(3);
      list.add(4);
      list.add(5);
      list.add(6);
      list.add(7);
      list.add(8);
      list.add(9);
      System.out.println("Original list : " + list);
      Collections.shuffle(list); // shuffling the list
      System.out.println("Shuffled list : " + list);
   }
}
```

Afterwards, use findById(x). And set the text of each box to list[i] depending on which number you would like from 1-9. This ensures a number is not used more than once.